# What .net StringComparison type is best for hostname comparisons?

Tags: .net, http, globalization

For Equals, should I do

hostname.Equals(theHostName, StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
or
hostname.Equals(theHostName, StringComparision.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
?

In 'IsAllowedHostName' should I do

hostname.IndexOf(badSubstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
or
hostname.IndexOf(badSubstring, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
?

Or for hostnames, is the correct answer neither of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the RFCs that define the DNS system. DNS host labels are case insensitive and may contain only the letters A-Z, 0-9 and '-'. A DNS name consists of 1 or more labels connected with an ASCII '.' (period, full stop).

Use `StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can be sure that there is no functional difference between using *OrdinalIgnoreCase* or *InvariantCultureIgnoreCase*.

However semantically you aren't interested in doing any natural language based comparison, so **OrdinalIgnoreCase** would be somewhat more logical. As a side effect it is also faster that InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.